# WINUI3 - Property value not update UI in observablecollection

Tags: winui-3, .net-8.0

I have created a new class that implement the communitytollkit mvvm.
This class is used to populate an observablecollection.
If I edit an item of that observablecollection, that item do not show the changes on UI.

this is the class item:

```
public partial class CompactContactData : ObservableObject
{
    public CompactContactData()
    {
    }

    string id;
    [JsonPropertyName("_id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get => id; set => SetProperty(ref id, value);
    }
    [ObservableProperty] string _nominativo;
    [ObservableProperty] string _strada;
    [ObservableProperty] string _civico;
    [ObservableProperty] string _cap;
    [ObservableProperty] string _comune;
    [ObservableProperty] string _provincia;
    [ObservableProperty] string _provinciaSigla;
 }
```

This is the observablecollection:

```
ObservableCollection<CompactContactData> _oc=new();
```

this is the snippet for change the item properties value.It is in an action method:

```
    private void UpdatedAction(ObjectReturnFromWebSocket<CompactContact> data)
    {
        if (data.Operazione == "Added" || data.Operazione == "Updated")
        {
            CompactContact contatto = data.Oggetto;
            if (data.Operazione == "Added")
            {
                CompactContactData _c = new();
                _dq.TryEnqueue(()=>contatto.SetPropertiesValue<CompactContact>(_c));//SetPropertiesValue is an extension method for set every property of item
                
                _oc.Add(_c);
            }
            else
            {
                CompactContactData contattoToUpdate = _oc.Where(c => c.Id == contatto.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (contattoToUpdate is not null)
                {
                    _dq.TryEnqueue(() => 
                    { 
                        contattoToUpdate.Cap=contatto.Cap;
                        contattoToUpdate.Civico=contatto.Civico;
                        contattoToUpdate.Comune=contatto.Comune;
                        contattoToUpdate.Nominativo="aaaa";// not change the property value in observablecollection
                        contattoToUpdate.Nominativo="test";// change the property value in observablecollection
                        contattoToUpdate.Provincia=contatto.Provincia;
                        contattoToUpdate.ProvinciaSigla = contatto.ProvinciaSigla;
                        contattoToUpdate.Strada=contatto.Strada;
                        
                        //contatto.SetPropertiesValue<CompactContact>(contattoToUpdate); 
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var contattoToDelete = _oc.Where(c => data.Ids.Contains(c.Id));
            if (contattoToDelete.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in contattoToDelete)
                {
                    _oc.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This same code work fine in an other case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x:Bind` is [OneTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#:%7E:text=Mode%20can%20be%20OneTime%2C%20OneWay%2C%20or%20TwoWay.%20%7Bx%3ABind%7D%20defaults%20to%20OneTime%3B%20%7BBinding%7D%20defaults%20to%20OneWay.) by default. Make sure the binding mode is `TwoWay`. For example:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Nominativo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: I'm just tried the code on an other pc and it work fine. Why? I must to clear the solution on the develop pc?

Comment: Not necessarily. But rebuilding is one of the things you want to try when your code is not working as expected. ;)

Comment: You're right, in the end. Once I added the "Mode=OneWay" in listview template, everything worked as expected. Thanks